# JSON Object property is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, undefined

I make an AJAX call to fetch some data, get the data back as a JSON Object (not a string).
When I log the object, I get the correct object and it's properties. However, when I try to log one of the objects properties, I get undefined.

For a screenshot of my code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWiq0.gif

For a screenshot of the console log:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/THp4s.gif

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't show your code as a screenshot, paste actual text into your question. _"[I] get the data back as a JSON Object (not a string)"_ - I think you mean that your Ajax response is a JSON string that jQuery parses for you to provide a JS object in your callback (there's no such thing as a JSON object).

Comment: JSON is a string by definition. If you create an object from it, then it's just an object, it doesn't know how it was created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your `POST` is returning data in an array, not as an individual object. I bet if you log `data[0].bursary_name`, you will see the correct logged output.

Comment: I have the very same problem and I tried your solution, didn't work. It seems my object is actually an object, because `typeof` gave me `object`. What should I do?